# How p4 recognizes a workspace directory?

Tags: perforce

In git the `git` command (unless explicitly specified) goes up the directory tree starting in current working directory looking for `.git` directory.

How `p4` command recognizes in is started in a directory inside workspace?

Answer (score 2):

`p4` uses the `P4CLIENT` environment variable to determine the current workspace, and the workspace definition on the server includes a `Root` directory that says where on the client machine the workspace lives.  If you only have one workspace on your machine, just do `p4 set P4CLIENT=my_client`.

If you have multiple workspaces on your machine and don't want to `p4 set P4CLIENT` each time you switch, you can use `P4CONFIG`, which allows you to set up per-directory config files:

```
p4 set P4CONFIG=.p4config
echo P4CLIENT=my_workspace1>~/workspace1/.p4config
echo P4CLIENT=my_workspace2>~/workspace2/.p4config
```

If `P4CONFIG` is set, `p4` goes up the directory tree from the working directory looking for a file with that name (I've called it `.p4config` here but it can be anything) and will read `P4` environment settings (`P4CLIENT`, `P4PORT`, `P4USER`, etc) from that file, having them take precedence over globally-set variables.

If `P4CLIENT` is not set in any way, the default value is the client hostname (which itself can be overridden with `P4HOST`).